# Is there an ubuntu setup guide for pure-ftp-mysql?

Tags: ftp

I've used google to find out how to set up pure-ftp-mysql after installing it with apt-get on ubuntu but I can't find anything that is related to ubuntu. Does anyone know where to find a ubuntu related post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 13.04 (nginx, BIND, Dovecot, ISPConfig 3)](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-13.04-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3). While he focuses on working with ISpConfig he also tell a lot about PureFTP and the rest.

Just keep in mind that you should use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su` to get a shell with root privileges - and omit software/packages you don't intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely to find good documentation and installation instructions on the sites that distribute the software you want to install. It is impossible for the OS to provide installation instructions on every piece of software that is out there.

Think of it this way: You have a cargo transporter driver (your OS) and some cargo you want to transport (your program). What makes more sense both economically and productivity wise, try to teach the driver every possible technique of cargo handling, or just include handling instructions on the cargo package?